# Find condition number of coefficient matrix in terms of singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

So what is the condition number of the coefficient matrix $\begin{bmatrix}I&A\\ A^T&0\end{bmatrix}$ in terms of the singular values of A if A has full rank and is m-by-n?

I'm assuming we have to use the SVD of A. So I was able to deduce that(if I'm wrong about this please correct it) $\begin{bmatrix}I&U\Sigma V^T\\ V\Sigma U^T&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}U&0\\ 0&V\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I&\Sigma \\ \Sigma &0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}U^T&0\\ 0&V^T\end{bmatrix}$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed further. Maybe I'm confusing what the books says in terms of coefficient matrix. The hint it provides says to use SVD of A

Comment: I don't agree with your product: you seem to assume commutativity e.g. $\Sigma U V^T ?=? U \Sigma V^T$

Comment: Also, as $A$ could be non-square, I am unconvinced that the product makes sense.

Comment: It has been corrected

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $A$ has full column rank, otherwise the block matrix in question is singular. Let $A$ be $m\times n$ with $m\ge n$.  If the induced $2$-norm is used, then $B:=\begin{bmatrix}I&A\\ A^T&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}I&\Sigma \\ \Sigma &0\end{bmatrix}$ have the same singular values. The latter matrix can be reindexed to $\begin{bmatrix}1&\sigma_1\\ \sigma_1&0\end{bmatrix}\oplus\cdots\oplus\begin{bmatrix}1&\sigma_n\\ \sigma_n&0\end{bmatrix}\oplus I_{m-n}$. Its $i$-th $2\times2$ sub-block have singular values $\frac12\left(\sqrt{1+4\sigma_i^2}\pm1\right)$. Therefore
$$
\sigma_\max(M)=\frac12\left(\sqrt{1+4\sigma_1^2}+1\right),
\ \sigma_\min(M)=\min\left\{\frac12\left(\sqrt{1+4\sigma_n^2}-1\right),1\right\}
$$
and you may readily calculate $\kappa(M)=\sigma_\max(M)/\sigma_\min(M)$.